# How to pass parameters to my applet using JarClassLoader AppletLauncher?

Tags: java, applet, classloader

AppletLauncher Class of JarClassLoader:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class MyAppletLauncher extends JApplet {

    private JarClassLoader jcl;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        jcl = new JarClassLoader();
        try {
            jcl.initApplet("MyApplet", this);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        jcl.startApplet();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        jcl.stopApplet();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        jcl.destroyApplet();
    }
```

From this, I have called my applet named  MyApplet as shown above:

```
jcl.initApplet("MyApplet", this);
```

From `<Applet> <param>` I was passing parameters to this MyApplet.
How to pass parameters to this MyApplet using this JarClassLoader AppletLauncher?

Comment: I don't know anything about applets but maybe what you really need is a "resource loader" for a property file rather than passing args?

Comment: The first question I have for you is - What is all this supposed to achieve for the end user?  Note that class loaders can typically only be created in a trusted applet, convince me (as an hypothetical user) of the 'must have' feature you can provide by using one.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an applet-related question. The question you want to ask is "How do you communicate between classloaders?".

Communicating between two classloaders is tricky. Here is an article on the subject:
http://surguy.net/articles/communication-across-classloaders.xml

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: yes it's a signed applet.. I have some native code dll's needed to be in jre path, this jarclassloader helping me to carry along and place natives in respective jre path..otherwise i have to copy paste native dll's manually on client machine...

Comment: A separate class loader is not necessary to deploy a JNI DLL and use it from an applet.

Comment: So what's the other way of transferring native dll to travel along with applet to client jre path? i have packed native dll as a jar, How to proceed?

Comment: It's not any different than if it were a normal app without an installer. Extract it to the right path before you need to call it and it will work.

Comment: Should i pack dll as a jar.. tried added that dll jar path to classpath.. It's giving error on running applet, native dll not found in java.library.path.. How to pass native dll to client on the load of an applet?